# react-native-router-flux: Nested router in components

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm trying to have independent modules with their own router, but so far I can't make it work.

Basically, I have the following defined in `index.ios.js`

```
<Router hideNavBar={true}>
    <Schema name="default" sceneConfig={Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight} />
    <Route name="start" component={Start}></Route>
    <Route name="main" component={Main}></Route>
</Router>
```

And I have a router in the component `Start`

```
class Start extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router name="startRouter">
                <Route name="login" component={Login} initial={true} rightTitle="Register" onRight={() => {
                    Actions.register();
                }} />
                <Route name="register" component={Register} title="Register" leftTitle="Login" />
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```

The navigation bar is properly rendered, but when I click the Register button, I get an error.

Do you have any idea how I can make this work?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I aslo get error in 4.0.0-beta.24.
it seems that nested router is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the syntax was when you asked the question, but with the current version (3.35.0) you don't use name, but key for your scenes.

The correct syntax would be:

```
class Start extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
              <Scene key="startRouter">
                <Scene key="login" component={Login} initial={true} rightTitle="Register" onRight={ () => Actions.register() } />
                <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register" leftTitle="Login" />
              </Scene>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```